# Is there a way to get parameters from a math-like function?

Tags: c#, .net

Considering the following string example:
`x + 1 (y * 8) ^ w,z example.test`


I would like to be able to get just:

x
y
w
z
example.test

Comment: What have you tried? No one is going to solve the problem for you, we are here to help not as a free work site. Anyway you could loop through each char and test if it's not a number or parenthesis and add it to a new string, list or whatever you want.

Comment: split parameters using `" "` an find needed elements in collection

Comment: Iterate string left to right, convert to Char representation. Check if it lies between ascii a (97) to ascii z (122)

Comment: @Fulalas I don't care if anyone profits from help that I freely give on stackoverflow or open source software, I am just stating the rules of the site, you explain your problem and what you tried to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Extract substrings that match a *regular expression* pattern:

```
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z_$\\.0-9]*");
var matches = regex.Matches("x + 1 (y * 8) ^ w,z example.test");
```

Iterate through a resulting `MatchCollection` to get strings representing relevant identifiers.